# Transfer img from redux store in react-konva

Tags: image-processing, react-redux, konvajs

User selects image from his pc. Then app reads file with `FileReader` as `DataUrl` and then the result is dispatched in store. And now I need to make an image for display from that `DataUrl`. I think it should be somehow transferred and parsed in react-konva.

```
inputImageChanged = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = evt =>
    this.props.dispatch(
      surfaceGridModalActions.inputSurfaceGridImage(evt.target.result)
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use that data url as image source:

```
class UserImage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: new window.Image()
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.image.src = this.props.dataURL;
    this.state.image.onload = () => {
      // so we need to update layer manually
      this.imageNode.getLayer().batchDraw();
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        image={this.state.image}
        y={250}
        ref={node => {
          this.imageNode = node;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```